# Create a query that groups by multiple categories?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, sqldf

I have these:

```
colnames(w)
[1] "user_id"         "install_date"    "app_version"     "user_session_id"
[5] "event_timestamp" "app_page"             "time_seconds"
```

I want to get the mean time of each of session per app_page (3 overall) so i did this. Since there are 3 app versions i would like to plot all these 3 pages with the avg app time used on them per version.

This is what i did:

```
df=sqldf('select app_version,app,round(avg(time_seconds),0) 
as time_app from w group by app_version')
df
```

which gives this:

```
  app_version app_page  time_app
1          v1 build     1019
2          v2 learn      910
3          v3 learn      966
```

but it doesn't look correct.
If i try this though

```
df1=sqldf('select app_version,app,round(avg(time_seconds),0) as time_app from w group by app')
df1

app_version app_page time_app
1          v2 build     1001
2          v2  draw      727
3          v2 learn      982
```

i think its correct but it has all the version included and not each one as a standalone.

Trying to plot it.

```
sw<-ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=app, y=time_app)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +facet_grid(app_version ~.)
sw
```

[image]

How to change the sql query so it gives the proper result and
thus the plot would provide each version with the avg time of every app page?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> plot would provide each version with the avg time of every app page

This sounds like an aggregation along two dimensions:

```
select app, app_version, round(avg(time_seconds), 0) as time_app
from w
group by app, app_version
order by app, app_version;
```

Comment: Thanks. can you tell me how the aggregation works at : `group by app, app_version` and if the `avg(time_seconds)` is indeed the average time per version in each app page?

Comment: @J_p . . . The `group by` keys define the rows for the result set -- each combination appears once.  The calculated values apply only to that row.